# Angular Activated Route not working on live site

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, routes

This question relates to Angular and Firestore.

I am working on a simple voting site, where a person will scan a QR Code and get sent to a website with the Firestore Document ID in the url string.

```
https://<my-website/vote/<documentID_String>
```

This works fine on localhost, but not on a live site.

Localhost: `http://localhost:4200/my/app/vote/1utI0PSDJPM48JREYj6M`

Live Site: `https://max-pinjarra.redhot.com.au/peoples-choice/vote/8H3XR4eImABcjlj9q4WS`

This is the expected result:
[image: Expected Result]

But on the live site, I get Page Not Found:
[image: Live Result and not what we want.]

in my app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'vote/:id', component: VoteComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: ''

  }
];
```

The QR Code will redirect to https:///peoples-choice/vote/

Website structure is: /
where sub-folder is an Angular app (admin. entrant, peoples-choice, etc).

I hope that makes sense....

I can't work out why this works on localhost and not on the live site.

Any help would be fantastic please!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is when you entering "/vote/:id" => you're asking the `server` for that vote route, which doesn't exist (as you're running client site angular app).

The solution is as follow:

1. Make sure your server (where you put the angular app) can serve static files.
2. Instructs the server to serve your angular app as static assets
3. From step 2, let say you tell your server that "*when I go to `mysite.com/vote`, you give me back my angular homepage*".
   What you should do now is open `index.html` in your angular app and change the `<base url` to `vote`

- Remember, step 3 tells your server to give the *homepage*, so you need a route - angular route/client route to go to other places/screens in your angular app. If you try to access something like `vote/id` by entering the url directly, you now again asking the server to give you the `vote/id` route.

I don't know what language of your server, don't know how you config your host/proxy. So it's just a general steps to follow. Hope my explanation is clear enough.
This is a common mistake when deploying to a server. I suggest you do some research on google, it will help you understand more about the issue.

Comment: Thanks @jimmy. I've researched Dr. Google and decided to ask here. Server is IIS on an Azure VM. I can set base href to /vote. That may do the trick. Not sure what common mistake you are referring to though. I've deployed loads of sites that run faultlessly on IIS. This one is a bit different though coz I'm calling a component direct with a query parameter. Thanks again for your input.

Comment: The common misunderstanding is "why my page 404, it's working fine on local", you can search for `deploy 404 angular`, it's not particular angular though but that search will give you the explanation.

Comment: If you can setup a local server, like nodejs/php/python... which can serve http, you can do it on your local first. This whole deploying thing is just you use your server to serve your static files which in this case is what the build --prod command gives you. Eventually, Angular/Vue/React is just a bunch of html/js files after you run the build command.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look in to the url of the localhost

"my/app/vote" I still don't understand you route fully but I think there is no sign of "my" in the actual website

I think that's the issue why it's not able to redirect , count the slash

Comment: That was something from Angular Docs. The problem existed before that change. Local host URL​ and the live site URL​ are /peoples-choice/vote/<document Id>

Comment: I removed that code and still had the same issue

Answer (score 0):

configure like following to the app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'peoples-choice/vote/:id', component: VoteComponent
},
{
    path: '**',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: ''
}];
```

Comment: Thanks. I get the same result. Page not found!